# Html file inside an AlertController?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Can I display the contents of an html file inside an UIAlertController?

I have a text for a terms of service and I already have it formatted within an html file. I would like to be able to display this in an AlertView when the user enters the app, so that they would have to click Ok.

Comment: You can use modal, Modal is better than alert.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8.0, and we're up to 9.3, so that's a pretty old method anyway.

Comment: @farshid modalViewController? that was deprecated in iOS 6.0

Comment: @BaseZen My apologies. UIAlertController. I've edited the question.

Comment: I could not find a way to do this, so I ended up coding my own faux-alert. Just use UIVisualEffectView and setting the UIWebView `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.clearColor()`. https://cloudup.com/c09XXIOcZMn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Modal Instance in which you can render the complete html page.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/